# Remove vertices to get k-connected components

Tags: graphs, greedy-algorithms, connected-components

In a graph, I need to remove some vertices in order to get at least k-connected components. The no. of removed vertices should be low. Is there a heuristic that I could follow for this?

Comment: Do you need to get $k$ connected components (as in "the number of connected components must be $k$"), or any number of components such that each component is $k$-connected (as in "removing up to $k-1$ edges does not disconnect the component")?

Comment: Have you seen Holberg, Walter. "The decomposition of graphs into k-connected components." Discrete mathematics 109.1-3 (1992): 133-145.?